# Форма обратной связи для MySQL

Tags: mysql, form

Не обессудьте, я только учусь.
В базе данных сайта на сервере в ISP Manager создал файл form.html. Вот он:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Add Record Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<p>
<label for="firstName">Имя:</label>
<input type="text" name="first_name" id="firstName">
</p>
<p>
<label for="lastName">Фамилия:</label>
<input type="text" name="last_name" id="lastName">
</p>
<p>
<label for="emailAddress">Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="emailAddress">
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
</body>
</html>**
```

Там же создал файл insert.php. Вот он:

```
    <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "ЗДЕСЬ ЛОГИН", "ЗДЕСЬ ПАРОЛЬ", "ЭТО ИМЯ ТАБЛИЦЫ");
    
    if($mysqli === false){
    die("ERROR: Нет подключения. " . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }
    
    $first_name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['first_name']);
    $last_name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['last_name']);
    $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['email']);
    
    // Попытка выполнения запроса вставки
    $sql = "INSERT INTO persons (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')";
    if($mysqli->query($sql) === true){
    echo "Записи успешно вставлены.";
    } else{
    echo "ERROR: Не удалось выполнить $sql. " . $mysqli->error;
    }

// Закрыть соединение
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

В phpMyAdmin создал таблицу. Вот она: https://www.htmlcssjs.ml

Открываю [www.htmlcssjs.ml/form.html](http://www.htmlcssjs.ml/form.html), заполняю форму, отправляю...и в ответ вот это:
ERROR: Не удалось выполнить INSERT INTO persons (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES ('', '', '').

Что не так делаю?

Comment: $first_name $last_name и $email пустые..

Comment: В таблице тип данных прописан int(11). Будет писать только числовые значения. Исправь на text. И добавь столбец id с автоинкрементом, пригодится.
И ещё, лучше так
`$first_name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['first_name']);`

Comment: $first_name $last_name и $email пустые?....А что там должно быть?

Comment: Тип данных я уже менял и на text и на varchar. Ничего не помогает.

Comment: В таблице нет индексного столбца с автоинкрементом.